# How to know what is consuming the CPU on my Ubuntu Lucid server running in Linode instace?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, cpu-usage

I've a Lucid 10.04 instance running on Linode which is hosting a simple rails3 app.

Now I'm getting several email complaining the CPU usage almost 100%.

But I'm not being able to figure out what is eating up the CPU.

So, is there any way out to figure out what program/component is consuming my server CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A visually-nicer alternative to `top` is `htop`, and it also has on-screen keys to sort by e.g. CPU use (default) and other columns. With `htop`, it is also easier to see the I/O load on your system.

Answer (score 2):

`top` >> <kbd>O</kbd> (o in capital) >> <kbd>k</kbd> >> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: whats that? Is it command to enter on `top` utility? How to issue that command, its confusing. Can u simplify on how to use the above command and what it does show?

Comment: run "top". while that's running, press "O" (capital O). it will sort processes in order of CPU consumption. Also, RTFM. Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

Second vote for HTOP.  HTOP is a much better read.  You can also pipe either top or htop to a text file if you wish as well.